# Using Triggers for Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

People tell me that using triggers is resource intensive and costly. I'm struggling to get my head around why in my particular instance. I've recently had to add "auditing fields" to some 50 tables (modifiedby, modifieddate, createdby and createddate). To save investigating EVERY stored procedure and program within our organization from having to add the modified by and modified date code in all instances I proposed creating the following trigger on each table. I guess my question is: Why would this be bad practice?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ctlgroups_update] on [results].[dbo].[ctlgroups]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SystemUser varchar(50)
    DECLARE @EmployeeID INT
    SELECT @SystemUser = REPLACE(system_user,'RTI\','')
    SET @EmployeeID = (select top(1) employeeid from ctlemployees with(nolock)
                         where lastname = reverse(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@SystemUser),1,charindex('.',REVERSE(@systemuser))-1))
                           and firstname = SUBSTRING(@SystemUser,1,charindex('.',@systemuser)-1))

    UPDATE ctlgroups
    set    ctlgroups.modifieddate = GETDATE(),
           ctlgroups.modifiedby = ISNULL(@employeeid,inserted.createdby)
    FROM   inserted
    WHERE  ctlgroups.groupID = inserted.groupid
END
```

Comment: If you really need *audit*, you'll usually realise that those `modified_` columns are inadequate - they tell you *who* did something *last* to a row but they don't let you know about the last-but-one user who actually performed the destructive update that you're wanting to look into.

Comment: In these cases it's more for telling when an update has been made so I can only select records that have been modified/created within a certain timeframe.

Comment: and yet you're including user identity. That's not needed for change tracking; and you ought to consider/use built in mechanisms for change tracking rather than implementing by hand. I know I sound critical, but it sounds as if you're not clear on *what you need to actually implement* here.